# Trouble debugging Java in Eclipse Galileo - appears to be in infinite loop

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

The user is on JDK6 u 18 with the latest Eclipse, and there appears to be an issue where Eclipse can't step through the debugger as it would normally.  Instead, the debugger is rapidly listing and delisting threads from what it looks like at the very bottom of the debug tree.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Is the application being debugged creating new threads? Could this just be normal behavior of the app itself?

Answer (score 0):

At least check with

1. other version of Eclipse
2. other JDK/SDK

first, to see how Eclipse and the JVM react to the program in the debugger.

What does "can't step through the debugger" mean? It hangs, it is slow, the refresh of the thread list is annoying...? Is your program rapidly creating and destroying thousands of threads?

Comment: Nothing is created threads... I double checked to make sure our class files weren't checked in.  Our latest candidate is the fact we use multiple versions of eclipse and we check in the .classpath and .project files.  Nothing else is checked in that is eclipse-specific.

Comment: What it looks like: The debug page shows no active threads during an attempt to debug, only the top-level and the first child.  The list has many empty entries which are rapidly increasing and decreasing which makes the scrollbars shrink and expand quickly.  Not able to step through anything at all.